# What Does This Regular Expression (RegEx) Flag Mean /iD

Tags: regex, plsql, ipv6

I'd like to use this regular expression for validating IPv6 but I want to understand everything it does **https://stackoverflow.com/a/1934546/3112803**

```
^(?>(?>([a-f0-9]{1,4})(?>:(?1)){7}|(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9](?>:|$)){8,})((?1)(?>:(?1)){0,6})?::(?2)?)|(?>(?>(?1)(?>:(?1)){5}:|(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){6,})(?3)?::(?>((?1)(?>:(?1)){0,4}):)?)?(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])(?>\.(?4)){3}))$/iD
```

but I don't know what this flag at the end does: `/iD`.  I know the `/i` flag means ignore case but I can't find what `D` does anywhere.  That answer has been upvoted a lot some I'm assuming its valid, but this post says there is no `D` flag: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4415233/3112803

I'm trying to use this in `PL/SQL` and it's not validing any valid string correctly:

```
if ( REGEXP_LIKE(v,'/^(?>(?>([a-f0-9]{1,4})(?>:(?1)){7}|(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9](?>:|$)){8,})((?1)(?>:(?1)){0,6})?::(?2)?)|(?>(?>(?1)(?>:(?1)){5}:|(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){6,})(?3)?::(?>((?1)(?>:(?1)){0,4}):)?)?(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])(?>\.(?4)){3}))$/iD') ) then
```

Comment: Specify what language you're using this under (the "flavor" of regex). Perl has its set of flags, as does PHP, as does PHP with preg (PCRE).

Comment: @PhilPerry I update question with that info.  I'm not trying to change the entire question.  This one is just for finding out what that flag means.  I'd do a separate question for why this isn't working in `PL/SQL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a flag in the PCRE flavour of Regex. See the note on the PHP.net manual page:

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php (under the code examples)

> D (PCRE_DOLLAR_ENDONLY) - 
>       If this modifier is set, a dollar metacharacter in the pattern matches only at 
>       the end of the subject string. Without this modifier, a dollar also matches 
>       immediately before the final character if it is a newline
>       (but not before any other newlines). This modifier is ignored
>       if m modifier is set. There is no equivalent to this modifier in Perl.

Comment: `There is no equivalent to this modifier in Perl.`  Yet another example of how the "Perl compatible" in PCRE is untrue.

Comment: Interesting ... Learn something new every day.

Comment: I'm not concerned with `PHP` or `Perl` for this question, but I do appreciate the info.  I'm trying to get IPv6 validation working in `PL/SQL` right now.  So I guess that flag doesn't apply to `PL/SQL`, correct?

Comment: @gfrobenius According to [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/oracle.html) oracle only supports `i`,`c`,`n`,`m`,`x`

Answer (score 1):

`D` flag is only valid in PCRE. Below is quoted from [PHP's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> `D (PCRE_DOLLAR_ENDONLY)`
>
> If this modifier is set, a dollar metacharacter in the pattern matches only at the end of the subject string. Without this modifier, a dollar also matches immediately before the final character if it is a newline (but not before any other newlines). This modifier is ignored if m modifier is set. There is no equivalent to this modifier in Perl.

### Summary

This regex in PCRE flavor matches the following format:

- IPv6: `2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334`
- IPv6 with leading 0's omitted: `2001:db8:85a3:0:0:8a2e:370:7334`
- IPv6 with longest consecutive groups of 0's (break-tie by leftmost) removed: `2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:7334`, `2001:db8::1:0:0:1`
- IPv6 dotted-quad notation: `::ffff:192.0.2.128`
- IPv4: `192.0.2.128`

Note that plain IPv4 is allowed, probably due to author's decision to support. It can be disallowed easily by removing `?` where I commented below.

The regex matches all valid IPv6 according to [section 2.2 of RFC 4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.2). However, it is not suitable for checking whether the IPv6 is in its canonical form as suggested by [RFC 5952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952#section-4.1)

### Pattern explanation

I use the term *hexa-group* to refer to a 16-bit group in an IPv6 address that is written in dotted-hexadecimal notation. And *deci-group* to refer to an 8-bit group in an IPv4 address that is written in dotted-decimal notation.

```
^
(?>
  (?>
                                    # Below matches expanded IPv6
    ([a-f0-9]{1,4})                 # (Hexa-group) One to 4 hexadecimal digits
    (?>:(?1)){7}                    # Match 7 (: hexa-group)

    |                               # OR

                                    # Below matches shorthand notation :: IPv6
    (?!(?:.*[a-f0-9](?>:|$)){8,})   # Can't find 8 or more hexa-groups ahead
    ((?1)(?>:(?1)){0,6})?           # Match 0 to 7 hexa-groups, delimited by :
    ::                              # ::
    (?2)?                           # Match 0 to 7 hexa-groups, delimited by :
  )
  |
                                 # Below match IPv4 or IPv6 dotted-quad notation
  (?>                            
                                 # Below matches first 96-bit of IPv6
    (?>                          
                                 # Below matches expanded notation
      (?1)(?>:(?1)){5}:          # Match one hexa-group then 5 times (: hexa-group)

      |                          # OR

                                 # Below matches shorthand notation
      (?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){6,})    # Can't find 6 or more hexa-groups ahead
      (?3)?                      # Match 0 to 7 hexa-groups, delimited by :
      ::                         # ::
      (?>((?1)(?>:(?1)){0,4}):)? # Match 0 to 7 hexa-groups, delimited by :
    )?                           # Optional, so the regex can also match IPv4

                                 # Below matches IPv4 in dotted-decimal notation
    (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9]) # (Deci-group) One IPv4 deci-group
    (?>\.(?4)){3}                               # Match 3 (. deci-group)
  )
)
$
```

You may wonder why I wrote `# Match 0 to 7 hexa-groups, delimited by :` for the part where you match short-hand notation for a IPv6 dotted-quad notation. It is due to pattern reuse via subroutine call `(?3)`. However, the regex is not wrong: due to the earlier look-ahead `(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){6,})`, it is not possible to find more than 5 hexa-groups when you are matching short-hand notation for IPv6 dotted-quad notation.

### Bug

By the way, there is a bug in the original regex. It fails to match `::129.144.52.38` due to the first non-backtracking group `(?>pattern)` disallowing backtracking, while the part of the pattern that matches IPv6 shorthand doesn't have sufficient check to make sure there is no IPv6 dotted-quad notation ahead. To put it simply: `::` can be a short-hand IPv6 and can also be the prefix to a IPv6 dotted-quad notation, and without backtracking the engine fails to match `::129.144.52.38`.

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/jD2zD6) (Note: `g` and `m` flags are for testing purpose)

One quick way to fix is to change the first `>` to `:`. All IPv6 should be matched correctly as intended.

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/zC6mG9) (Note: `g` and `m` flags are for testing purpose)

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it's not working for all my test cases, and doesn't work at all in `PL/SQL`. I have been trying to find a **IPv6 only** solution for a while and still can't find one.  Here was my initial attempt to find one: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631669/regular-expression-regex-for-ipv6-separate-from-ipv4**.  Here are my latest test cases: **http://regex101.com/r/sV5cZ3**.  Yours doesn't work for a few of the tests. I'm beginning to think my test cases are not valid. This question was more fore just figuring out the `/D` flag.  The link above is for finding a pattern.

Comment: @gfrobenius: The code is not even mine. It is the same as whatever you picked up from the other question.

Comment: @gfrobenius: Actually, there is a slight bug in the original regex, but it should not concern you, since what you are looking for is a regex that works in PL/SQL

Comment: @gfrobenius: By the way, the original regex is testing that the whole string contains only the IPv6. If you want to test multiple strings separated by new line, you need `g` and `m` flags. http://regex101.com/r/jD2zD6

Comment: Thank you so much.  I awarded you the answer on my other question related to this topic, this one was more for just the `/D` and @SmokeyPHP answered that first.

Comment: @gfrobenius As I mentioned _last time_, some of your "valid" test cases are not actually valid. This is why you are still having trouble.