# Regex pattern loop

Tags: php, regex, loops

I ve got an string that have an specific format, which i want to check. To check if this format is correct i want to use regex. But the string format "12345x" can be endless. Example "12345t12345x".

My regex pattern for the format if it used only once is:

```
function useRegex($input) {
    $regex = '/^[0-9]+[a-zA-z]+$/i';
    return preg_match($regex, $input);
}
echo useRegex("12045t");
```

If the string is "12345t12345u" my code cant check it. So my question is if i can loop my regex pattern through the string?

Comment: Just use `preg_match_all('~\d+[A-Z]+~i', $input, $matches)` to extract all these matches. If you want to validate a string use `preg_match('~^(?:\d+[A-Z]+)+$~iD', $input)`. If you need to both extract and validate, it will be a bit more complex, but possible.

Comment: That dont work for my string format. The format ist everytime 5 random number from 0-9 then one random char, and this format can be loop or stack infinity. And i want to check this exact format with regex. But the length is not static and can be individuel so i need an regex pattern that can be infinit

Comment: So,  `preg_match('~^(?:\d{5}[A-Z])+$~iD', $input)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
preg_match('~^(?:\d{5}[A-Z])+$~iD', $input)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/POYxpq/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\d{5}[A-Z])+` - one or more occurrences of:

  - `\d{5}` - five digits
  - `[A-Z]` - a single ASCII letter (case insensitive, due to `i` flag)
- `$` - end of string.

[`D` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940348/what-does-this-regular-expression-regex-flag-mean-id) stops matching if there is a trailing `\n` at the very end of string. If trailing newline is allowed, you may remove the flag.